# What is Engineering stance on questions "checking" the correctness of ChatGPT answers?

Tags: discussion

For example, let's say I asked chatgpt to make a calculation about a certain subject, I checked out the math and the equations and it is all a-ok.

However, I copy and paste the answer on engineering, asking if the answer is correct/incorrect/missing something.

Would this a valid question for the website?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's SE Engineering stance on chatGPT answers?](https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/668/whats-se-engineering-stance-on-chatgpt-answers)

Comment: @SolarMike Yes. Thanks.